# taglib -> dependency injection pojo/service how?

Tags: dependency-injection, taglib

Is there a nice way to dependency inject using a jsp taglib?

either using ejb 3.0, spring, or guice...

I have a lot of services/pojos that I would like to use in my taglibs

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [Seam](http://www.jboss.com/products/seam), it enables you to refer to a component by name. However, the released version is JSF based, but that's changing.

Answer (score 0):

just stumbled upon your question because I plan to do the same. You can actually use Spring and its @Configurable annotation (with AspectJ load-time or compile-time weaving) to inject services into your tag implementations. For a detailed explanation of all options have a look at Ramnivas' blog post [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/01/23/new-improvements-in-domain-object-dependnecy-injection-feature/).

Hope to help in case you still need a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to your injector on the servletContext and then use in each tag as you need it.  See

In your Guice setup:

```
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {

@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(blah, blah);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    servletContext.removeAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
    super.contextDestroyed(servletContextEvent);
}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    Injector injector = getInjector();
    ServletContext servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    servletContext.setAttribute(Injector.class.getName(), injector);
    super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
}
```

}

And then in your taglib:

```
@Singleton
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MySampleTag extends TagSupport {
@Inject private MyInjectedService myService;

@Override
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    Injector injector = (Injector) pageContext.getServletContext().getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
    injector.injectMembers(this);

    String value = myService.doSomething();
            etc.
            etc.
```